# Invalid conversion from uint8_t* to uint32_t - when migrating from 32 to 64bit architecture?

Tags: c, memory, type-conversion

I had a little function which converted virtual memory address to physical on a 32-bit architecture:

```
uint32_t VIRTBASE;

uint32_t getPhysForVirt(void* virt) {
  uint32_t offset = (uint8_t*)virt - VIRTBASE;
  return PHYSBASE + offset;
}
```

It compiled and worked without any single issue in last 10+ years.

I've changed the compiler to build the repo for newer architectures (now with 64bit support for the first time).

Compilation fails stating

> invalid conversion from ‘uint8_t*’ {aka ‘unsigned char*’} to ‘uint32_t’ {aka ‘unsigned int’} [-fpermissive]

Now, I understand the message, but I'm not sure about the necessary steps to make this compiling without errors.

I'm only sure in that I don't want to enable  *-fpermissive*.

Comment: What's `VIRTBASE`?

Comment: *It compiled and worked without any single issue in last 10+ years.*  What gives you the impression it's OK in any way, shape, or form to try to cram any pointer into a `uint32_t`?  Code that does that is - to put it bluntly - utter crap.  If you're now supposed to make it work, you have a lot of work to do.  I wouldn't trust anything from whoever wrote that POS (not "point-of-sale"...)

Comment: And you haven't even seen the other stuff it's mangling! Directly accessing memories of DMA registers and instructing it to copy data from here to there.. :)

Comment: I don't want to see it  ;-)

Comment: We'd really need a lot more information to help you port this code. It's quite unclear what it means by a virtual address. Does it just mean an address in the process virtual address space, that is, a normal address/pointer? If so, what is a physical address exactly? Is this for inter-process communication and addresses inside shared memory with a different base address in each process?

Comment: I'm a little bushed: this thing leads to deep inside of an ARM CPU's insights - way too deep to discuss it here. However, there are a few comments and an answer already, and someone voted up the question. I'd just delete it, but I'm unconvinced.

Comment: `permissive` in Visual Studio allows non-conformance rules, it works if the program is tied to Windows. When you switch to x64 build it disables `permissive`. But this code doesn't make any sense even in that context. It's unclear what compiler you use (and where did ARM come in?)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You use the wrong types. C language has special types for casting pointers to integral values.

```
uintptr_t VIRTBASE;

uintptr_t getPhysForVirt(const void * restrict virt) {
  ptrdiff_t offset = (uintptr_t)virt - VIRTBASE;
  return PHYSBASE + offset;
}
```

If the rest of code is written the way as this function was - you have plenty work for Christmas.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/integer

Comment: I suspect OP's calling code and `PHYSBASE` needs an update to handle the new return type.  Yes, plenty work for Christmas.

Comment: Silent DV-ter. Can you explain what in my answer was deserving the DV?

Answer (score 0):

You are doing pointer arithmetic and casting it directly to a 32-bit unsigned integer.

On a 32-bit architecture, pointers are also 32-bit unsigned integers, so this was likely silently handled in the background.

Now, on your 64-bit architecture, you're subtracting two 64-bit pointers and storing the result in a 32-bit integer -- and therefore losing half of your address!

You probably don't actually want this function to be returning an integer at all, but rather a pointer to whatever datatype you're actually using (presumably uint8_t*, since that's explicitly stated in the function itself).

edit: Conversely, maybe you actually meant to dereference `virt` and subtract its value, rather than do pointer arithmetic? If so, you have the `*` operator in the wrong spot. Try:

```
  uint32_t offset = (uint8_t) *virt - VIRTBASE;
```

Though as another commenter pointed out, this would cause issues with dereferencing a void pointer. You'd have to cast it to something meaningful first.

Comment: I'd accept this, because it satisfies my initial question in my mind. Note: `*` operator is *not* in the wrong spot, it was just worked okay on 32bit. Result of this function is feed into direct memory addresses of the CPU, so trying to "make this compile" is wrong way. I'll have to properly rewrite this based on the official documentation of the CPU.

Comment: @Daniel use the correct types instead of magic

Comment: This definitely seems completely wrong an won't even compile (can't use unary `*` on a `vod *`) -- you're trying to dereference the pointer to get a single byte then subtracting VIRTBASE from that byte, which seems nonsensical.

Comment: @ChrisDodd ...have you read the post? Casting a pointer subtraction to a uint32 is *already* nonsensical. Besides, OP already confirmed that the 2nd interpretation was not what's going on in his code.

Comment: Treating a uint32 as an address is only non-sensical on a non-32-bit machine, and the obvious fix of replacing uint32_t with a type of the correct size seems much more reasonable

Comment: "On a 32-bit architecture, pointers are also 32-bit unsigned integers, so this was likely silently handled in the background." is an overstatement. Although that is common, on a _32-bit architecture_, pointers are not specified by C to be 32-bit unsigned integers.  C allows much latitude in an implementation.